# iOS - In which thread ios selectors run

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uibutton, selector

When we addTarget on a UIButton or a view for example, with below code,

```
cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.onCancelPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

in which thread `onCancelPressed` code runs? I assume they run on main thread, but is it always assured that they never runs from other thread? on other hands, should i put ui stuffs inside main block in `onCancelPressed` or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calls to selectors run on main thread as UIButtons are created on main thread. Invocation of functions also originate from the main thread, even if you add a target-selector from a secondary thread. 
Hence there is no need to add a main block within the selector function.